# Meaning of ssh_get_issue_banner() failure in libssh

Tags: libssh

When I call ssh_get_issue_banner() under libssh, I get a NULL (failure) back even though "ssh -vvv" shows a myriad of welcome messages. Why would this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if an issue banner, specifically, is not configured (e.g. is commented) with your SSH server, as they, often, are not.

Dustin